# Question about the collection of pairwise disjoint cycles

Tags: combinatorics

> A collection of non-overlapping cycles is unique up to rearranging the cycles and the cyclic order of the elements within cycles.

Suppose $\pi = (1, 2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 6, 8).$ There are different ways of rewriting this $\pi$. Does it mean that this particular $\pi = (1, 2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 6, 8)$ is unique **until** we write it down in different ways, like $\pi = (4, 8, 6) (7, 2, 1)(5, 3)?$ If so, how do we prove it?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that disjoint cycles commute and cyclic shifts do not alter the permutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase is badly formulated, since as collection of cycles things like permuting the cycles or cycling elements in an individual cycle does make a (perceivable) difference. However what is meant that these variation will still correspond to the same *permutation*. So for a fixed permutation, all ways of writing it as collection of disjoint cycles can be converted into one another by reordering cycles and cycling elements in individual cycles. Since these are considered somewhat trivial modifications the form is called *unique up to* these variation.

Comment: Is it possible to write the same permutation as a collection of disjoint cycles in two different ways? The answer is apparently no. I just don't get it. Can you explain this, please.

Comment: In your question you already wrote $\pi$ as a collection of disjoint cycles in two different ways, but you did it wrong, since you must retain the _cyclic_ order in each cycle. So $\pi = (1, 2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 6, 8)$ can also be written $\pi = (6, 8,4)(7, 1, 2)(5, 3)$, but $\pi \ne (4, 8, 6) (7, 2, 1)(5, 3)$, which is _another_ permutation.